# PHP remove empty spaces and tabs inserted into code by IDE (PhpStorm)

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm wondering if there is a way to remove all the empty spaces and tabs the IDE (PhpStorm) is inserting during a code format. For instance i have this PHP code:

```
<small class="text-muted">
    <?= $order->get('sender_city') ?> (<?= $order->get('sender_postalcode') ?>)
</small>
```

and the result is something like this:

```
<small class="text-muted">
" Cityname (99999) "
</small>
```

in some other similar cases, the code can be like this

```
<small class="text-muted">
"     Cityname (99999)     "
</small>
```

Apparently PhpStorm formatting space and tabs goes directly into HTML output. Any way to stop this? Maybe through phpstorm configuration, or some PHP ways?

Comment: Are you sure this is caused by the IDE and not `&nbsp;`s somewhere or formatting of the actual text?

Comment: I'm sure, I'm not manually adding ```&nbsp;``` s. If I write my code on a single very long line, without any indentation, the output is clean. But when I hit the auto-indentation keyboard shortcut, or I indent the code myself, spaces and tabs are added in the output too.

Comment: You can configure your Code Style for HTML at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | HTML`  -- look at the `Other` tab in particular. **HINT:** you can insert your own code sample in the formatter preview area and preview the formatting changes live.

Comment: *"Apparently PhpStorm formatting space and tabs goes directly into HTML output."* Arhmm ... that's HTML whitespace (you nee to use it if you want code/tags indentation). There is nothing wrong wit it. If you want the content of your `<small>` tag (between opening and closing tags) to be without extra whitespaces that instruct the IDE to inline (or not to touch) such tags so it remains in a single line.